# Issue with submit post using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-post

I am having problems of submitting a post using jquery , Below is the code snippet:

Jquery

```
 $("#pay").click(function () {

        if ($("#terms").attr("checked")) {
            $("#frmWorldPay").submit();
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Please agree to the terms and conditions.");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

View

```
<form method="post" action="https://secure.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase" id="frmWorldPay">
                    <input type="hidden" name="instId" value="261901" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="<%: Model.GUID %>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP" /></form>

<div id="worldPayBtnWrap">

                   <p> <%: Html.CheckBox("terms") %> by ticking this box you are agreeing to our <%: Html.ActionLink("terms & conditions", "Terms", "About")%></p>
                        <input type="image" src="/content/images/btnWorldPay.png" alt="Pay via World Pay" id="pay" />
                    </div>
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: code seems ok, use debug in submit() method.

Comment: its not posting it to the action which is https://secure.......

Comment: how to use debug in submit.....

Comment: If it isn't posting, what *is* it doing?

Comment: Please show your HTML code after execution in your browser.

Comment: it is reloading the same page

Comment: submit method is defined in the form-submitting library u included. put alerts or console.debug to watch values.

Comment: I tried debugging it is going to form submission but it is not redirecting to the secure page

Comment: then problem should be in ur purchase action

Comment: remove your return statement, i am not getting what the requirement of return after submit

Comment: return removed with no success

Comment: print some values in purchase function. just to make sure that every thing before this is working fine. some values means hidden values being posted

Comment: I tried this .. but its not showing any alert message that means its not submitting :  <form method="post" action="secure.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase"; id="frmWorldPay" onSubmit="alert('Form submitted')>

Comment: if form is not posting, it means ur html has problem

Comment: There's an extra ; and a missing " there

Comment: @awais: get help from firebug, that will guide u better

Comment: Do *not* remove the return statement; just because you've submitted the form doesn't mean you don't need `return false` to tell your image click to do nothing.

Comment: i sorted out actually i was using the nested form to post ... there is nothign wrong with the code thats what firebug says .. thnx for all your help cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning false, not true.  True causes it to go ahead and submit the form that the image is in (even though you just triggered a submit on a different form) or, apparently, if the image isn't in a form, causes it to reload the page.

Comment: I want to call the submit () ... Thats the requirement

Comment: Ah, I missed seeing the close tag of the form you want to submit.  It is reloading the same page because you are returning true; don't do that.

Comment: then you will have to return false no matter what result really is

Comment: Well using return = false for both occurence, it doesnt reload the page neither it redirects to the post page

Comment: If you add a submit event handler to the secure form that does an alert, do you see that get triggered?

Comment: Alert message appears when I add  if ($("#terms").attr("checked")) {
            $("#frmWorldPay").submit(); alert("hi");

Comment: i did something like this : <form method="post" action="https://secure.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase" id="frmWorldPay" onSubmit="alert('Form submitted')>

Comment: but the alert message doesnt appears

Comment: which library are you using for formsubmission?

Comment: If you put a button in the secure form and press it, does that work?

Comment: @MLS: but he doesn't want an ajax submit, afaict